# Explain who commands 4th column

Tags: who

I have graphical machine of rhel7 , when i run who command , the output of 4th column is ':0' , what does that mean? When my other machine take access of this graphical machine , the output of who commands 4th column is ip address of the machine that took the graphical machine's ssh , please explain why so.

Comment: `man who` and `who -H`.. You are like walking through all the columns.

Comment: shall we call Doctor Who ?

Comment: @Archemar Well, `who` only outputs 4 cols and I think this question is the last one.

Comment: @Arthur2e5 - that answer is for the 2nd column - I'll post another answer here for the 4th column and hopefully get some points :-)

Comment: @garethTheRed wait, .. ah, you are right, 2nd col may contain `:0` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The fourth column (comment column) is actually the column, as you have said, that displays the IP address of the machine through which the user has logged in. Meaning of `':0'` is that the IP address of the machine is `localhost` and nothing else. Which means the user is logged in from the same machine where the OS is installed and not any other machine in the network

Edit: I must say that this site does not work like the way you used it. You should have made thorough research attempts and then you should have posted this question. A simple google search gave me this http://linoxide.com/linux-command/linux-who-command/